# How can @JsonValue be used for Swagger enum values using springdoc-openapi with a Lombok getter

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, lombok, springdoc

Given a Spring Boot project that uses the [springdoc-openapi](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) library to expose an [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) (Swagger) endpoint documenting the Spring MVC controller endpoints of the project.

One of the enums in the project uses [`@JsonValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) from [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) on a field to change the JSON representation of the enum.  This enum field is exposed as a getter using the [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) annotation from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org):

```java
@Getter
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

    @JsonValue
    private final String name;

    Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

However, despite the Jackson representation being based on the field, the enum representation returned by the OpenAPI endpoint uses the `toString` value of the `enum` instead:

```json
"suit": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "HEARTS",
    "DIAMONDS",
    "CLUBS",
    "SPADES"
  ]
}
```

Expected:

```json
"suit": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "Hearts",
    "Diamonds",
    "Clubs",
    "Spades"
  ]
}
```

Based on [springdoc-openapi#1244](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1244) and [swagger-core#3998](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3998), it's clear that the `@JsonValue` annotation needs to be applied to the method, and not the field.  However, neither the above attempted approach, nor the following, work:

```java
@Getter @JsonValue
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

    private final String name;

    Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

How can this enum be exposed with the proper values in Swagger, while still using Lombok to generate the getter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to tell Lombok to use the annotation on the generated getter method, using `@Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonValue)` on the field.

```java
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

    @Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonValue)
    private final String name;

    Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

The `onMethod` property is documented in the [@Getter and @Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) and the [onX](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) documentation:

> To put annotations on the generated method, you can use `onMethod=@__({@AnnotationsHere})`.  […] For more details see the documentation on the [onX](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) feature.

> The syntax is a little strange and depends on the javac you are using.
> On javac7, to use any of the 3 `onX` features, you must wrap the annotations to be applied to the constructor / method / parameter in `@__(@AnnotationGoesHere)`. To apply multiple annotations, use `@__({@Annotation1, @Annotation2})`. The annotations can themselves obviously have parameters as well.
> On javac8 and up, you add an underscore after `onMethod`, `onParam`, or `onConstructor`.

Answer (score 0):

As of `swagger-core` 2.2.5, the [swagger-core#3998](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3998) issue has been resolved, and the field-based annotation should work.  This version is used by Springdoc version 1.6.13 and later.

```java
@Getter
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS("Hearts"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds"), CLUBS("Clubs"), SPADES("Spades");

    @JsonValue
    private final String name;

    Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```